# Confused on Fourier Transform. What is amplitude spectrum and phase?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I can't understand how can I get the second formula by using the Euler formula on the first equation. How can I get ride of the summation symbol?
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to "get rid of the summation symbol"?

Comment: No, I don't. But the second equation does not have the summation symbol. I don't know why.

Comment: Because they didn't insert it there. There's no benefit to adding it there, so they didn't.